# Can someone explain how this works please

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var message = '';
var user;
var student;

function print(message) {
  var outputd = document.getElementById('output');
  outputd.innerHTML = message;
}


var students = [ 
  { 
   name: 'Dave', track: 'Front End Development', achievements: 158, points: 14730 },
  { name: 'Jody', track: 'iOS Development with Swift', achievements: '175',  points: '16375'
  },
  { name: 'Jordan', track: 'PHP Development', achievements: '55', points: '2025'
  },
  {  name: 'John', track: 'Learn WordPress', achievements: '40', points: '1950'
  },
  { name: 'Trish', track: 'Rails Development', achievements: '5', points: '350'
  }
];


function studentreport( studen ){

  var report = '<h2>student: ' + studen.name + '</h2>';
  report += '<br>'+ 'track: ' + studen.track + '</br>';
  report += '<br>' + 'achivements: ' + studen.achivements + '</br>';
  report += '<br>' + 'points: ' + studen.points + '</br>';
  return report
};

while (true){
  user = prompt("what student are you looking for?");
   if (user === 'quit'){
    break;
   }

   for (var i = 0; i< students.length; i += 1){
    student = students[i];
     if (student.name === user){

   message = studentreport(student);
    print(message);
  }   else if (student.name !== user){
      alert('no student with that name, try again');
  }

   }



}
```

so i understand all the code but at the end 
if student.name === user  so from here if that is /true then the student report function runs with the student argument. But how does
it get the index for the student argument? like how does it know which
name/where to start on the array object above, is that passed from the
if statement if so how? I'm just really confused on this part. */

Thank you all for the help

Comment: `students` is an Array. Arrays index their contents, starting with `0`. You have a loop that goes from `0` to one less than the number of items in the Array. The loop variable increments by one upon each iteration. That variable is used to isolate each array item, one at a time.

Comment: prompt method is used to ask the user for a student name or quit after that
for (var i = 0; i< students.length; i += 1) is looping through the students array of objects and when the input name is matching it will store the found student in the student variable and after that it will call the studentreport method.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is actually looping over every student in the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i< students.length; i += 1){ /CODE GOES HERE/ }
```

The `i` is used as the index. We test `students.length` to determine how many iterations and `i+=1` increments `i` on each iteration loop. Giving us the ability to `students[i]` access each element. Does this help?

Comment: Take a look at this article. Nicely laid out: https://dev.to/kartik2406/better-loops-in-javascript-2716

Answer (score 0):

So the main section of interest in your codes is everything in the while loop. So let's have a look at what is happing inside that loop.

```
// Here we start the while(true) loop so until we break this will keep running
while (true) {
  // Now we ask the user for a students and
  // and save it to a variable called user. 
  user = prompt("what student are you looking for?");

  // Here we check if the user has typed quit and if so break the loop
  if (user === "quit") {
    break;
  }

  // This is the important part:
  // Here we create a for loop and it will keep looping until
  // it no longer less than the length of the student array.
  // This means that the i variable can be used as the current index 
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
    // Each iteration of the loop we save the current student ( student[i] )
    // to a variable called student.
    student = students[i];

    // Remember that each student in the array is an object. 
    // Since we saved that object to the student variable we can now access
    // the name property of that object by calling student.name

    // So here we are now just checking if student.name is equal to the 
    // name the user entered.  
    if (student.name === user) {
      // If the the name matches, we have found our student and we can now
      // generate a student report. We save this report to a variable message.
      message = studentreport(student);
      // Finally we print out this message.
      print(message);
    } 

    else if (student.name !== user) {
      // If the current student doesn't match the inputed name then
      // we alert an error message.
      alert("no student with that name, try again");
    }
  }
}
```

One small issue is that the error message will be alerted multiple times until the current student we are looking at in the loop matches the users input. In order to fix this we can modify our code slightly.

```
while (true) {
  user = prompt("what student are you looking for?");
  if (user === "quit") {
    break;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.name === user) {
      message = studentreport(student);
      print(message);
      // Once we find the student we are looking for we can break out of the loop
      break;
    }
  }
  // This code will never get reached if we find the student 
  // because we break out of the loop. But if we don't find the
  // student then we can alert the user.
  alert("no student with that name, try again");
}
```

I hope this helps! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

If the code was formatted properly if would be much esier to read.

```
while (true) {
  user = prompt('what student are you looking for?');
  if (user === 'quit') {
    break;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.name === user) {
      message = studentreport(student);
      print(message);
    } else if (student.name !== user) {
      alert('no student with that name, try again');
    } // It is easy to see where the if and else are
  } // It is easy to see this is the end of the for loop
}
```

But would be much easier to read in a modern functional style over for loops.

Using a while loop like that means that the UI thread is locked and you will not see any results until you type quit. Use event handlers and the UI thread is free to update. Having a search button that runs your code on a click event means that there is no continually running blocking code loop.

```js
function print(message) {
  var outputd = document.getElementById('output');
  outputd.innerHTML = message;
}

var students = [
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    track: 'Front End Development',
    achievements: 158,
    points: 14730
  },
  { name: 'Jody', track: 'iOS Development with Swift', achievements: '175', points: '16375' },
  { name: 'Jordan', track: 'PHP Development', achievements: '55', points: '2025' },
  { name: 'John', track: 'Learn WordPress', achievements: '40', points: '1950' },
  { name: 'Trish', track: 'Rails Development', achievements: '5', points: '350' }
];

function studentreport(studen) {
  var report = '<h2>student: ' + studen.name + '</h2>';
  report += '<br>' + 'track: ' + studen.track + '</br>';
  report += '<br>' + 'achivements: ' + studen.achivements + '</br>';
  report += '<br>' + 'points: ' + studen.points + '</br>';
  return report;
}

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const user = document.getElementById('user').value;

  const student = students.find(s => s.name === user);
  if (student) {
    const message = studentreport(student);
    print(message);
  } else {
    print('no student with that name, try again');
  }
});
```

```html
what student are you looking for? <input id="user" type="text"><button id="search">Search</button><br>

<div id="output"></div>
```